# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tide'

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm calling tide in the pytides module with Python3.7, which is installed using the pip method.Here is my python code:

```
from pytides.tide import Tide
```

I ran into the following problems:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tide'

What should I do to solve this problem?

[image]

This is my link to the petides installation package, and you can see the full code here
[enter link description here](https://github.com/sam-cox/pytides)

Comment: There are a few possibilities. Do you have a python file/directory named "pytides" in the same directory as the file that is raising the error? Can you check that pytides is installed correctly for the correct interpreter by running `python3 -m pip freeze` ("python3" should be replaced by however you are calling your script) and checking that pytides is present in the output

Comment: My pytides file is in the scripts folder under the Python installation path.When i ran python -m pip freeze Pytides will appear in the list.@Iain Shelvington

Comment: Can you add the full traceback to your question and the files and directories that are in the directory you are running the script from?

Comment: I have upgraded my question@Iain Shelvington

Comment: Are you using some kind of pydev/pycharm plugin to run your code?

Comment: I am writing a Python program using pycharm. How do I verify that I am using a plug-in?I'm a novice programmer@Iain Shelvington

Answer (score 1):

I think you should you

`from pytides import Tide`

It will work, correct me if it doesn't

Edit 1:

```
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev libatlas-base-dev gfortran
export LAPACK=/usr/lib/liblapack.so
export ATLAS=/usr/lib/libatlas.so
export BLAS=/usr/lib/libblas.so
pip install numpy
pip install scipy
pip install pytides
```

Comment: I still get an error when I run the program the way you suggested
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tide'

Comment: I think it haven't installed properly, please can you try  ```import pytides```

Comment: I am programming with pycharm, and when I type 'import pytides' in the console, it will also prompt: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tide'.
I have installed pytides a number of times using the pip method.What should i do to install it correctly.

Comment: Which OS you are you using if it's Ubuntu or any Linux try above method I edited in answer

Comment: I'm very sorry that I may not have made myself clear in the question.I program in pycharm software in a Windows environment .Numpy and scipy are already installed on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem in `\site-packages\pytides\__init__.py`

You need to rewrite:

```
from . import tide
from . import astro
from . import constituent
from . import nodal_corrections
```

Same problem in `\site-packages\pytides\constituent.py`

You need to change

```
from . import nodal_corrections as nc
```

and you need to add:

```
from functools import reduce
```

And again in `\site-packages\pytides\tide.py`

You need to change:

```
from .astro import astro
from . import constituent
```

Answer (score 0):

The pytides is outdated. Use pytides2, the newer version. Other thing to keep in mind is,if your interpreter is miniconda/anaconda, then you can't obtain it from their repository. You must create a 3.7 (and no later version) interpreter in pycharm using python3 (real or virtual environment, either is fine).